# TypeORM OneToMany and ManyToOne relations cases 500 error on GET request

Tags: postgresql, orm, nestjs, typeorm

After adding OneToMany and manyToOne relations in the entities and doing GET request it shows in postman 500 error.

// Car entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'car' })
export class Car {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  car_id: number;
  @Column()
  name: string;
  @Column()
  enabled: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(() => Person, (person) => person.cars)
  person: Person;
}
```

// Person entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'person' })
export class Person {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  person_id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  enabled: boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => Car, (car) => car.person)
  cars: Car[];
}
```

// Postman

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/v2/cars",
    "method": "GET",
}
```

**UPDATE**
In try catch it shows this error

ERROR QueryFailedError: column Car.personPersonId does not exist

//Service
GET request to fetch cars by person id

```
async getByPersonId(
    personId: string | number,
    relations: string[] = [],
    throwsException = false,
  ): Promise<Car[] | []> {
    return await this._carRepository.getByPersonId(
      personId,
      relations,
      throwsException,
    );
  }
```

// Repository

```
async getByPersonId(
    personId: string | number,
    relations: string[] = [],
    throwsException = false,
    enabled?: boolean,
  ): Promise<Car[]> {
    const where: IPersonById = {
      person_id: personId,
    };

    if (!isNil(enabled)) {
      where.enabled = enabled;
    }

    return await this.find({
      where: {
        ...where,
      },
      relations,
    })
      .then((entities) => {
        if (!entities && throwsException) {
          return Promise.reject(
            new NotFoundException(
              'Car is not found by provided person id.',
            ),
          );
        }

        return Promise.resolve(entities ? this.transformMany(entities) : null);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('ERROR', error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: It's likely that there's a problem with the service or controller.

Comment: @HamidrezaVakilian 
In try catch it shows this error
ERROR QueryFailedError: column Car.personPersonId does not exist

Comment: Can you provide your service source code where you are performing the find query?

Comment: @HamidrezaVakilian I have added service and repository in the description, please check

Comment: It's a bit difficult for me to say where the problem comes from unless I debug your project. I would suggest setting logging=true in your Typeform config. The SQL will be printed in the console and you can diagnose what leads to **Car.personPersonId** column in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

on the Car entity:

```
@ManyToOne(type => Person, person => person.cars, {eager: false})
    person: Person
```

on the Person Entity

```
@OneToMany(type => Car, car => car.person, {eager: true})
    cars: Car[];
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not help
in try catch it gets this error
ERROR QueryFailedError: column Car.personPersonId does not exist

Comment: You are having column issues, what is the point to have one id and one car_id in the car table?

Comment: Yes you are right, in the table there is not id, just car_id as a primary column, thank you for noticing. But the problem still exists.

Comment: First of all you have to make sure that there is no PersonId column on the cars table, in the moment when you do the manytoOne relation a person column will be generated for you .
Second: after you check the first step, you need to remove the dist folder in order for the database to refresh (sometimes it does not refresh itself), you can achieve this by running the following command  rm -rf /dist    (while being on the app directory). After that run : npm run build